# Can I create a window whose client area is transparent (using transparency key) and be click through?

Tags: c#, transparency

Using C# I create a window whose border is normal, but the client area is transparent (using the transparency key).  On XP I was able to click through this (accessing the items below the transparent area); however, this doesn't work on W7.  Is there a way to make this work for W7 (and XP)?

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to all for the quick responses!  Looks like the key to my problem was the unlucky fact that I happened to use YELLOW as my transparency key.  I wanted it to stand out in Visual Studio so that I would remember that it was transparent; and that color choice is what was keeping click-through from working.  As soon as I changed to a backcolor that was gray, it worked fine.

Comment: Try  [Gray](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowscompatibility/thread/2e9205b8-b78f-471e-8fed-dc07d7e5fdae)?

Comment: Interesting... For some reason I picked YELLOW as my transparency key color.  When I change it to GRAY, it now does click-through.  Does that make any sense to anyone?

Comment: Anurag, I'd like to set your response as the ANSWER, but you'll have to post it as an actual answer for me to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowscompatibility/thread/2e9205b8-b78f-471e-8fed-dc07d7e5fdae), the workaround is to set the TransparencyKey to `Gray`

```
  this.BackColor = Color.Gray;
  this.button1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
  this.TransparencyKey = Color.Gray;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.TransparencyKey = this.BackColor;
```

This works fine for me in Windows 7.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not quite doing that.  I set a color for the transparency key, then assign the backcolor to that same color (essentially the same, but different).  And that allows you to do "click-through"?

Comment: Also the window is set to TopMost = true, since the notepad becomes active instead of Form1 after I start printing.

Comment: I'd be curious to know if your BackColor is some shade of Gray (R=G=B); cause it appears to me that 'gray' is important.  If I have backcolor set to transparencykey, but don't use gray, then click-through doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, I just discovered you are right. Yellow seems to be not through-clickable for me too.